# Searching within strings in a single field containing an in-field delimiter across two files using awk?

Tags: awk, grep, mapping

I have two files.

`file01.tab`:

```
Q86IC9   PGEN_.00g000010
P04177   PGEN_.00g000020
Q8L840   PGEN_.00g000050
Q61043   PGEN_.00g000060
A1E2V0   PGEN_.00g000080
P34456   PGEN_.00g000090
P34457   PGEN_.00g000120
O00463   PGEN_.00g000210
Q00945   PGEN_.00g000230
Q5SWK7   PGEN_.00g000240
```

`file02.tab`:

```
Q86IC9;Q552T5                                                omt5
P04177                                                       Th
Q8L840;O04092;Q9FT71                                         RECQL4A
Q61043;A0A1Y7VJL5;B2RQ73;B7ZMZ9;E9Q488;E9Q4S3;Q674R4;Q6ZPM7  Nin
A1E2V0                                                       BIRC3
P34456                                                       Uncharacterized
P34457                                                       uncharacterized
O00463;B4DIS9;B4E0A2;Q6FHY1                                  TRAF5
Q00945                                                       RING
Q5SWK7;Q8BXX5;Q9CXG1                                         Rnf145
```

I want to use the first column in `file01.tab` to join with the first column in `file02.tab`. I could do this with `grep`, but I need the output to be formatted in the following fashion:

```
PGEN_.00g000010 Q86IC9;Q552T5           omt5
PGEN_.00g000020 P04177                  Th
QPGEN_.00g000050 Q8L840;O04092;Q9FT71   RECQL4A
```

I've come very close to success using the following `awk` code:

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} ($1 in a){print $2,a[$1]}' file02.tab file01.tab
```

That one-liner will produce the following:

```
PGEN_.00g000020 P04177  Th
PGEN_.00g000080 A1E2V0  BIRC3
PGEN_.00g000090 P34456  Uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000120 P34457  uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000230 Q00945  RING
PGEN_.00g000280 Q8ZXT3  protein
PGEN_.00g000300 Q5REG4  DTX3
PGEN_.00g000450 A0JMR6  mysm1
PGEN_.00g000490 Q7D513  Hercynine
PGEN_.00g000530 A6H769  RPS7
```

The code does *not* find matches in `file02.tab` `$1` where there is an in-field semi-colon delimiter. It will only find matches that have a single entry in `$1`.

Obviously, `grep` can handle the searching using two input files, but I don't know how to format the output from the `grep` results, since the formatting requires info from both input files.

Is there any way to accomplish this with an `awk` one-liner or should I put together a small script instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v FS='[;[:space:]]+' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {print a[$1], $0}' file01.tab file02.tab
```

Output:

```
PGEN_.00g000010 Q86IC9;Q552T5                                                omt5
PGEN_.00g000020 P04177                                                       Th
PGEN_.00g000050 Q8L840;O04092;Q9FT71                                         RECQL4A
PGEN_.00g000060 Q61043;A0A1Y7VJL5;B2RQ73;B7ZMZ9;E9Q488;E9Q4S3;Q674R4;Q6ZPM7  Nin
PGEN_.00g000080 A1E2V0                                                       BIRC3
PGEN_.00g000090 P34456                                                       Uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000120 P34457                                                       uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000210 O00463;B4DIS9;B4E0A2;Q6FHY1                                  TRAF5
PGEN_.00g000230 Q00945                                                       RING
PGEN_.00g000240 Q5SWK7;Q8BXX5;Q9CXG1                                         Rnf145
```

- `FS='[;[:space:]]+'` splits the line on a sequence of semicolons or space
  characters.
- I have switched the order of files for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Are you able to explain why the field containing semi-colons has to be split in order for `awk` to find the matching string in those lines?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
        n=split($1,s,";"); 
        for(i=1;i<=n;++i) a[s[i]]=$0; 
        next;
    } ($1 in a){print $2,a[$1];}
' file02.tab file01.tab
```

you get,

```
PGEN_.00g000010 Q86IC9;Q552T5                                                omt5
PGEN_.00g000020 P04177                                                       Th
PGEN_.00g000050 Q8L840;O04092;Q9FT71                                         RECQL4A
PGEN_.00g000060 Q61043;A0A1Y7VJL5;B2RQ73;B7ZMZ9;E9Q488;E9Q4S3;Q674R4;Q6ZPM7  Nin
PGEN_.00g000080 A1E2V0                                                       BIRC3
PGEN_.00g000090 P34456                                                       Uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000120 P34457                                                       uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000210 O00463;B4DIS9;B4E0A2;Q6FHY1                                  TRAF5
PGEN_.00g000230 Q00945                                                       RING
PGEN_.00g000240 Q5SWK7;Q8BXX5;Q9CXG1                                         Rnf145
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is only about matching the first value in the semicolon delimited string, you can also use split and compare the first value:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{split($1,p,";");a[p[1]]=$0; next} ($1 in a){print $2,a[$1]}' file02.tab file01.tab
```

Or removing all starting at the first semicolon:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x=$1;sub(/;.*/, "", x);a[x]=$0; next} ($1 in a){print $2,a[$1]}' file02.tab file01.tab
```

Output

```
PGEN_.00g000010 Q86IC9;Q552T5                                                omt5
PGEN_.00g000020 P04177                                                       Th
PGEN_.00g000050 Q8L840;O04092;Q9FT71                                         RECQL4A
PGEN_.00g000060 Q61043;A0A1Y7VJL5;B2RQ73;B7ZMZ9;E9Q488;E9Q4S3;Q674R4;Q6ZPM7  Nin
PGEN_.00g000080 A1E2V0                                                       BIRC3
PGEN_.00g000090 P34456                                                       Uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000120 P34457                                                       uncharacterized
PGEN_.00g000210 O00463;B4DIS9;B4E0A2;Q6FHY1                                  TRAF5
PGEN_.00g000230 Q00945                                                       RING
PGEN_.00g000240 Q5SWK7;Q8BXX5;Q9CXG1                                         Rnf145
```